# Passing Variables to ctest

Tags: cmake, ctest

Is there a way besides environment variables to pass information to ctest?

with cmake there is:
cmake -DVAR=VAL

With CTest I've been using: 
VAR=VAL ctest

which works fine for bash but not other shells....any thoughts?

Tony

Comment: In CTest, the tests are common executables, so passing CMake variables to them has no sence. As for passing environment variable to `ctest`, you may use `cmake -E env VAR=VAL [...] ctest`. This will work in any shell.

Comment: This is perfect!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may use [command-line tool mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode) of `cmake` for run a program (`ctest` in your case) with modified environment:

```
cmake -E env VAR=VAL [...] ctest
```